# Webmatrix, Razor, and Sessions

Tags: session, razor, webmatrix

I'm getting some funky behavior with session variables with Razor .cshtml pages.  Essentially on some pages I check to see if a Session variable is set, and if not I set it.  I keep getting a null object reference.

I believe this is because ultimately Razor is designed for MVC, and I did a little reading about the MVC life cycle and apparently the session object is injected a a different point in the lifecyde then say asp.net webforms.  So When I try to use it on my pages it isn't available yet.

So my question would be for simple sites based with Razor (not MVC yet, but moving that way) what would be an effective way to check if a session variable is set (like say "access level") that is checked fairly often.  That would be part one of the question.

Part two of the question would be if this is bad practice, what then should I be doing to replace this approach?

Thank you for your input.

Comment: can you add the code for a simple page that repros your issues?

Comment: if put a simple @{ if (Session["xxx"] != null) { bla bla... } } And you will get the error occasionally (yes break the lines up). If I use one of the Render methods like @RendorPage the sessions seem to work ok on the rendered page.  Again, I think this is a MVC life cycle issue, just wondering if their is a easy/lazy man fix.  If not, I figure I'll have change the way I use Sessions, which may be a good thing depending on alternatives (encryped cookies say for one), but it is kind of a bummer. Like new tools, just don't like old ones taken away.

Comment: Maybe you have to come up with a more explicit scenario. From my point of view Session is working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Razor view pages in ASP.NET MVC 3 execute in an almost identical manner to ASP.NET Web Pages with Razor syntax. And for the record, Razor was first developed for Web Pages and not for MVC - we later reworked it to make sure that it was a "first class citizen" in both scenarios.

As such, Session state should work just fine no matter where you use it - from within a Web Pages file, an MVC controller, or even an MVC view (though most would argue that using Session state from within an MVC view is a bad practice).

Comment: Well, even simplistic examples aren't working consistently for me (sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't). But for now I'll assume either my code or my server is f'ed up (don't think it is the code, as again it works sometimes, but stranger things have happened). So I'll take this answer.